# RxJava emit a default value if observable doesn't emit after a certain time

Tags: android, observable, rx-java

I need help with rxJava's observables. I have an observable, **myObservable**, that may provide a single boolean value emission. If **myObservable**, doesn't emit a value within a few seconds I want to fall back to a default value. AFAIK, **timeout** only works for subsequence values. Could someone please help me find a way to handle this.

```
myObseravble
    .timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
    .as(autoDisposable(this))
    .subscribe(
        booleanValue -> {
       // do something
        },
        irrelevant -> {
         // value not recieved from myObseravble, default logic
        });
```

Comment: `timeout` does work for when the very first item is late. You can see this via `Observable.never().timeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Observable.<Object>just("timeout"))`.

Comment: Indeed timeout will work for the first value.

timeout(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
. onErrorReturn(error -> yourDefaultValue)